# Get all values for a certain key from a list of dictionaries with a single command

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
c = [{'text': 'LahoreRightNow', 'indices': [111, 126]},
    {'text': 'PakvsSL', 'indices': [127, 135]}]
```

I want access the text of both the dictionaries. I can get them with `c[0]['text']` and `c[1]['text']`.

Isn't there a way to do this using a single command ?

Comment: `res = [subdict['text'] for subdict in c]`

Comment: Define "command" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a list comprehension satisfies your single command constraint, use

```
>>> [dic['text'] for dic in c]
['LahoreRightNow', 'PakvsSL']
```

which is shorthand for

```
>>> result = []
>>> for dic in c:
...     result.append(dic['text'])
... 
>>> result
['LahoreRightNow', 'PakvsSL']
```

It does not get more single-command-esque than the comprehension here, but you could hide the `for` loop if you prefer the functional programming style:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter('text'), c)
['LahoreRightNow', 'PakvsSL']
```

(convert the map-object to a list in Python3 with `list(map(...))`.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access all `text` keys in a single operation from a list of dictionaries.

You can create a function, but this function perform an operation on each dictionary individually.

What you *can* do is create a new dictionary after performing the aggregation yourself. The optimal way to do this is via `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for my_d in c:
    for k, v in my_d.items():
        d[k].append(v)

# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'text': ['LahoreRightNow', 'PakvsSL'],
#                              'indices': [[111, 126], [127, 135]]})
```

Then `d['text']` will return the list you require.

[@timgeb's list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49646847/9209546) is fine for the single key case. But the above method will be more efficient if you have multiple keys.

Comment: I think you took the *"single command"* a bit too seriously\technically.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, you're possibly right. I'm leaving this answer in case other (technical?) users find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this short approach:

```
print(list(map(lambda x:x['text'],c)))
```

output:

```
['LahoreRightNow', 'PakvsSL']
```